# Why is my PyGame application not running at all?

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I have a simple Pygame program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("My first game")
```

But every time I try to run it, I get this:

```
pygame 2.0.0 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.8.3)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

And then nothing happens.
Why I can't run this program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application works well. However, you haven't implemented an application loop:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("My first game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:

    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # update game objects
    # [...]

    # clear display
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # draw game objects
    # [...]

    # update display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # limit frames per second
    clock.tick(60) 

pygame.quit()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop#main.py)</kbd> See also [Event and application loop](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_event_and_application_loop.md)

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. Computer read your program line by line[python]. When all the line are interpreted, the program closed. To solve this problem you need to add a while loop to make sure the program will continue until you close the program.

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("My first game")
win = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))

#game loop keeps the game running until you exit the game.
game_running=True
while game_running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:            
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    win.fill((0, 250, 154)) #Fill the pygame window with specific color. You can use hex or rgb color
    pygame.display.update() #Refresh the pygame window
```

You can check more pygame Examples.
https://github.com/01one/Pygame-Examples
I think this will be helpful.