# Pygame window closes instantly

Tags: python, pygame

My pygame window closes without any errors right after I run the code
Here's my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()   # initialises pygame

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))   # width, height

pygame.display.set_caption("Project_01")
```

If anyone can help, thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

See [Why is my PyGame application not running at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65264616/why-is-my-pygame-application-not-running-at-all/65264742#65264742) Your application will exit right after the window is created. You have to implement an application loop. You must implement an application loop to prevent the window from closing immediately:

```py
import pygame 

pygame.init() # initialises pygame
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500)) # width, height
pygame.display.set_caption("Project_01")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # draw scene
    # [...]

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```